# Why does FullCalendar renders this event as single day event?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

This is JSON representation of event:

```
    "id" : 253,
    "title" : "16-17",
    "allDay" : true,
    "start" : "2015-04-16T00:00:00.000+03:00",
    "end" : "2015-04-17T00:30:00.000+03:00"
```

FullCalendar renders it as single day event. I suspect that the problem is in timezone settings, but can't understand what exactly.

I've tried to use: `ignoreTimezone: false` but it didn't help.

I suppose that JSON above will render full day event from 16th to 17th (two day event).

Thank you.

**UPDATE**: 
I'm using FullCalendar v2.3.1 and there's a link to jsfiddle which reproduces this issue: http://jsfiddle.net/anatoly314/m8d68v1b/4/

Comment: What does the rest of your fullcalendar config look like? I put this data into a sample fullcalendar fiddle and got the behavior you say you're expecting: http://jsfiddle.net/wzwm8Lqz/

Comment: @SMcCrohan, I'm at home already will check and post tomorrow full config. Thank you!

Comment: @SMcCrohan, actually I've looked at your code and paid attention that you've used old version of FullCalendar 1.5.4, in a new version 2.3.1 I will be able to reproduce this issue. There's a line http://jsfiddle.net/anatoly314/m8d68v1b/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the automated tests in the current version of FullCalendar appear to cover the case in which the start and end dates include times AND the `allDay` option is set.

Documentation indicates that end dates are exclusive. I strongly suspect that what is happening is that with `allDay : true`, fullCalendar is stripping the times off of the start and end dates and treating them as `T00:00:00`. At that point, your event has a start time of `2015-04-16T00:00:00.000` and an end time of `2015-04-17T00:00:00.000`, which matches the behavior you're seeing. In fact, if you omit the times from your data and give it:

```
start: '2015-04-16',
end: '2015-04-17'
```

it produces a one-day event.

It looks like if you want your event to span two days, you'll need to 'round up' your end time to the beginning of the next day.

Comment: Actually It was written in the manual, I was need to read it carefully.   `It is the moment immediately after the event has ended. For example, if the last full day of an event is Thursday, the exclusive end of the event will be 00:00:00 on Friday! `  What was confused me that in the old version it behaves differently and I migrate from old version to new one. Thank you.