# rfc2445, how to store all day events?

Tags: fullcalendar, icalendar, rfc5545, rfc2445

I'm creating a calendar application which should be complaint with [rfc-2445 specification](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445.txt). I've had a few issue with the **All Day** events here but now it has been resolved, you can see the SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29732516/why-does-fullcalendar-renders-this-event-as-single-day-event/29734681#29734681) but it forced me to ask the following question.

The matter that when I choose **All Day** event for example from 20-10-2015 up to 21-10-2015 (duration of the event is 2 days) actually I need to create record in DB from 20-10-2015 up to 22-10-2015, otherwise it will shown as one day event.

> And my question has two part:
>
> 1. Is the above right and according to standard rfc-2445?
> 2. Should I store such event in DB as from 20-10-2015 to 22-10-2015 and when show its details to end user I should decrease **one day** from **end date** or store it as 20-10-2015 to 21-10-2015 and increase by **one day** at **end date** when render it inside the calendar.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DTEND property corresponds to the non-inclusive end of the event, so, your above example is correct

See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.6.1 which specifies:

> The "DTSTART" property for a "VEVENT" specifies the inclusive
> start of the event.  For recurring events, it also specifies the
> very first instance in the recurrence set.  The "DTEND" property
> for a "VEVENT" calendar component specifies the non-inclusive end
> of the event.

and also has an example of a multiday allday event:

> The following is an example of the "VEVENT" calendar component
> used to represent a multi-day event scheduled from June 28th, 2007
> to July 8th, 2007 inclusively.  Note that the "DTEND" property is
> set to July 9th, 2007, since the "DTEND" property specifies the
> non-inclusive end of the event.

```
   BEGIN:VEVENT
   UID:20070423T123432Z-541111@example.com
   DTSTAMP:20070423T123432Z
   DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20070628
   DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20070709
   SUMMARY:Festival International de Jazz de Montreal
   TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
   END:VEVENT
```

You would have noticed that I'm refering to RFC5545 which has obsoleted RFC2445.

Comment: Thank you. Finally I got the idea.

Comment: Hi, I've returned to this project, forgot that I've already asked it and has been answered by you, asked again and found my question. I once again got the idea except one moment, if we have time part in DTSTART and DTEND, and DTEND is exclusive, does it mean that last second of the event formally isn't part of the event? For example `DTSTART:20151223T060000Z
DTEND:20151223T070000Z`  Thank you again.